# Mysql query to get records which created exactly 1 day ago

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to automate email notification system.

I want to send a email 24 hours after a new record is created.

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
  WHERE t.created_at = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

This code not works.

How can I compare exact 24 hours ago.

I already created cron job to trigger every minute.

Comment: This is just a bad idea.  You need to batch the requests -- say by hour or day -- and look for records during a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try first to add simple quotes around your interval if you're experiencing syntax errors.

```
INTERVAL '24 HOURS'
```

Also, you're very unlikely to get any results with this query since you asking for records that are 24 hours old… to the nearest nanosecond ! Try allowing a reasonable grace delay :

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
  WHERE t.created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '24 HOURS')
    AND t.created_at <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '23 HOURS')
```